# Counting a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count, rows

Suppose that I have a column named '$' and in it I have different values, for example:

```
id|| $ 
======
1 || 50
======
2 || 54
======
3 || 76
======
```

How can i add the values of $? A query that would give me 50+54+76? The real table has around 20,000 rows.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but your question shows a complete lack of knowledge in SQL and the total unability to use manuals.

Comment: well... even from that lack of knowledge someone else with much more knowledge than me learned something new too... the important thing is to contribute at least a little grain of sand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM($) FROM your_table_name
```

I'm not sure $ is a valid column name though

**UPDATE**
Tested in PHPMyAdmin and I was able to name a column `$` and perform a `SUM` on it. Something new learned!

Comment: You beat me by one freaking second. ;D

Comment: @Thomas Carpenter It was one of those questions where you know everyone is coming up with the same answer and it's just a matter of who gets there first! :)

Comment: Extra tidbit: you can then do a group by third_column. Check out the mysql docs on group statements, @luqita

Comment: mysql can use strange names by enclosing the column names in ''

Comment: @nabuchodonossor Good point. In this case, the backticks weren't even necessary. Surprising!

Comment: thanks, what if I had two tables and want to sum the $ from them?

Answer (score 2):

```
select sum($) from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SUM()` function. Since I don't believe you can have a column named `$` (and even if you can, it seems there would be unintended consequences), I've named your column `amount`

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total FROM your_table;
```

**Edit** As mentioned by @Brendan you can have a column named `$`. I stand by my opinion that it would be confusing in code :)